# Issue while trying to select first item in combobox: VBA MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have following code to populate the Combobox

```
StrSQL = "Select BankID, BankName As [Please Select Bank] from tblBank"
With Me.cmbBankSearch
  .RowSource = StrSQL
  .ColumnCount = 2
  .BoundColumn = 1
  .ColumnWidths = "0in.;1in."
  .ColumnHeads = True
  .LimitToList = True
  .Requery
  .Value = "Please Select Bank"
End With
```

But due to some reasons I am not able to select first item which is "Please select Bank"

Am I doing something wrong?

As per the comment below I changed it to like below code.

```
StrSQL = "Select 0 as BankID, 'Please Select Bank' As [Please Select Bank] from tblBank UNION Select BankID, BankName As [Please Select Bank] from tblBank"

With Me.cmbBank
  .RowSource = StrSQL
  .ColumnCount = 2
  .BoundColumn = 1
  .ColumnWidths = "0in.;1in."
  .ColumnHeads = True
  .LimitToList = True
  .Requery
End With
```

Comment: 'I am not able to select first item which is "Please select Bank" ' - do you have a record called "Please select Bank" in your table? it seems that's the name of the column. you're not supposed to be able to select column name in a combobox. You may want to do `Select 0 as BankID, "Please Select Bank" As [Please Select Bank] from tblBank UNION Select BankID, BankName As [Please Select Bank] from tblBank`

Comment: Now I am getting first record duplicate. See the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz3QV.png I added the updated code above

Answer (score -1):

This should be enough (values from combo/listboxes are always strings):

```
StrSQL = "Select BankID, BankName As [Please Select Bank] from tblBank"
With Me.cmbBankSearch
  .RowSource = StrSQL
  .ColumnCount = 2
  .BoundColumn = 1
  .ColumnWidths = "0in.;1in."
  .ColumnHeads = True
  .LimitToList = True
  .Value = "0"
End With
```

Edit - to not have column heads:

```
With Me.cmbBankSearch
  .RowSource = StrSQL
  .ColumnCount = 2
  .BoundColumn = 1
  .ColumnWidths = "0in.;1in."
  .ColumnHeads = False
  .LimitToList = True
  .Value = "0"
End With
```

Comment: but issue still persist. Why am I not able to select first record(Please Select Bank)

Comment: That's because you set ColumnHeads to True. That is the first entry.

Comment: if I set the `ColumnHeads = False` , this will not even show as "Please Select Bank" as first record. My question is: How can I let the user to select option "Please select Bank" if there is already any database record selected in combobox